# Compilation Error on #include <algorithm> Algorithm:No such file or Directory

Tags: iphone

I want to use OpenCV and Open SURF libraries in one project along with ARToolKitPluas then it gives me error **"Algorithm:No such file or Directory"** which i tried my best to fix but can't. Please Help me. Really i am in trouble and need your help.

Thanks

Comment: Check you spelling and capitalisation - it's `<algorithm>`, not `<Algorithm>` or `<Agorithm>`.

Comment: Dear I checked it , its <algorithm>. I think it is due to the build properties. Means Project -> Edit Active Target in xcode.

Comment: OK - it is mis-spelled in your question (see above), so if you copied and pasted the actual error message to your question then you have a typo. If you just made a mistake when you re-typed the error message then please edit the question to fix this in order to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is probably being compiled as ObjC or C. It should be C++ (.cpp) or ObjC++ (.mm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I have changes my file to .mm but it still gives the same error. If you want then i will send the code to you. Please i need little bit push because i am new to iOS programming.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem Solved by setting the following

1. `#import <opencv/cv.h>` in `.pch` file
2. Providing path for includes in `Header` search path
3. Providing path for libraries in `Library` search path
4. Also changing class name to `.mm`
5. writing this `-lstdc++ -lz` in `Other` linker flags
6. And most important issue that i observed is that the project folder name should not   contain space for example if project folder name is AR Camera then change it to ARCamera otherwise it will give errors

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not added `Application.mk` file in your project.